# Do I need to play the first game?

Tags: the-darkness-2, the-darkness

Do I need to play The Darkness to understand what's happening in The Darkness II, Or is it as easy as reading up on the plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is highly recommendable to play the first game before. You will comprehend and appreciate better the second one. You will know the characters, the world, and so on. Besides, Darkness 1 is a very nice game and you will enjoy it.

**But is not necessary**: At the beginning of the Darkness II you have a really complete prologue that will tell you all you need to know.

Comment: It's like impossible to find the darkness online too. Steam doesn't sell it. And the only shop that does is like 60km away from me xD

Comment: @Charkz have you looked on Amazon?

Comment: I have not. But I imagine that Play.com and Amazon will charge P&P and the game will be a lot dearer, but I'll check now.

Comment: @Charkz It was afaik never on PC, that is why you cannot get it on Steam.